# Can't find a way to add new item when it doesn't exist using Vue-Treeselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete, vue-treeselect

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with a list I have populated from the backend. Here's the library in question [Vue Treeselect](https://vue-treeselect.js.org/)

Once the user tries to enter something that's not inside, I want to be able to dynamically add it, and later when the request gets submited, create that value on the backend. However, the library doesn't seem to provide a way to override the default behaviour. Here's what I tried so far.

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-sutherland-i5e8f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container mt-4 mx-auto">
      <treeselect
        @search-change="handleSearch"
        :multiple="true"
        :options="options"
        placeholder="Select your favourite(s)..."
        no-results-text="No results found... Press enter to add"
        v-model="value"
      >
      </treeselect>

      <pre class="bg-gray-200 text-gray-600 rounded mt-4 p-4">{{
        JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)
      }}</pre>

      <h5>Search text: {{ text }}</h5>
      <button
        @click="appendNewItem"
        class="focus:outline-none text-white text-sm py-2.5 px-5 rounded-md bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 hover:shadow-lg"
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import the component
import Treeselect from "@riophae/vue-treeselect";
// import the styles
import "@riophae/vue-treeselect/dist/vue-treeselect.css";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Treeselect,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      lastId: 0,
      text: "",
      value: [],
      options: [
        { id: 1, label: "Option #1" },
        { id: 2, label: "Option #2" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleSearch(ev) {
      this.text = ev;
    },
    makeId() {
      return `new-item-${++this.lastId}`;
    },
    appendNewItem() {
      this.options = [...this.options, { id: this.makeId(), label: this.text }];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Even my button solution doesn't work, because as soon as you leave the area of the tree-select input, the text gets reset to an empty string, so pressing the button adds an empty text.

Given the current documentation of `Vue-Treeselect` how can I make it call my `appendNewItem()` function when the user presses `enter` and the treeselect has no results?

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
<treeselect (other-props)>
    <template #no-results={ node }>
       <span>No results found for {{ node.text }}</span>
       <button @click="appendNewItem">Add {{ node.text }}</button>
    </template>
</treeselect>
```

But, unfortunately this is not supported by the library API. And it still doesn't solve the question of "creating a new field when enter key is pressed" but it would be a nice start regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have to say, this is a tough one.

The library doesn't provide a way to enable the functionality you've described but what you can do is use some low-level Vue APIs to override the library methods and try to achieve the effect you need.

Essentially, we're gonna override the `select(node)` function from the library in an attempt to make it bend to our needs.

```
<script>
import Treeselect from "@riophae/vue-treeselect";

export default {
  extends: Treeselect,
  data() {
    return {
      overridesLastNodeId: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    overridesFindValue() {
      if (this.$refs.control) {
        const childRefs = this.$refs.control.$refs;

        if (childRefs["value-container"]) {
          const valueContainer = childRefs["value-container"];

          if (valueContainer.$refs.input) {
            return valueContainer.$refs.input.value;
          }
        }
      }

      return null;
    },
    overridesCheckValueInNodes(value) {
      let childHasValue = false;

      this.traverseAllNodesDFS((node) => {
        if (node.label === value) {
          childHasValue = true;
        }
      });

      return childHasValue;
    },
    select(node) {
      /**
       * Here we override the select(node) method from
       * the library, we will inject a new node if a node
       * doesn't exist and then proxy this method to the original!
       */
      const value = this.overridesFindValue();
      if (typeof value === "string" && value.length === 0) {
        // This function gets called internally a lot, so we need
        // to make sure it's proxied when there is no value
        return Treeselect.mixins[0].methods.select.call(this, node);
      }

      if (value && value !== "") {
        if (this.overridesCheckValueInNodes(value)) {
          // If there is a value, we just fallback to the default function
          this.resetSearchQuery();
          return Treeselect.mixins[0].methods.select.call(this, node);
        }
      }

      /**
       * Finally, here's the solution to your question.
       * We can emit a new node here, call your append function
       * sending it the ID and making this work.
       */
      const id = `new-node-${++this.overridesLastNodeId}`;
      this.$emit("new-node", { value, id });

      /**
       * Additionally, to make the select select our value
       * we need to "emit" it to v-model as well
       */
      this.$emit("input", [...this.value, id]);

      /**
       * Finally, let's reset the input
       */
      this.resetSearchQuery();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Then, remember to use the overridden component in your code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container mt-4 mx-auto">
    <treeselect-extended
      :multiple="true"
      :options="options"
      placeholder="Select your favourite(s)..."
      no-results-text="No results found... Press enter to add"
      v-model="value"
      @new-node="appendNewItem"
    />
    <pre class="bg-gray-200 text-gray-600 rounded mt-4 p-4">{{
      JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)
    }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TreeselectExtended from "./overrides/TreeselectExtended";
import "@riophae/vue-treeselect/dist/vue-treeselect.css";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      value: [],
      options: [
        { id: 1, label: "Option #1" },
        { id: 2, label: "Option #2" },
      ],
    };
  },
  components: {
    TreeselectExtended,
  },
  methods: {
    appendNewItem({ value, id }) {
      this.options = [...this.options, { id, label: value }];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This IS a working solution, however, I would have to recommend using this code with caution, as it creates dependencies with internal implementation with the library! That means if you update the library from `package.json` you're introducing a breaking change to your project even in case of minor version updates! Because this code relies even on "private" functions from the library, and not just the public-facing API. You could try to future-proof it, but it might be smarter to just opt-in and use some different library that does provide your needs.

Here is a Codesandbox that demonstrates this: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/treeselectoverriden-3hfqt)